# My garage lift only works if the light switch is on!

Tags: doors, garage

I just moved into a house where I couldn't get the garage door to open until I figured out that the switch on the wall turned the lift AND the light on. And the light has to be on in order for the lift to work. I would like to make that a double switch, or even better set it where the garage lift is always powered. Is this do-able? Simply?

Comment: 1. Turn off the power to the circuit at the breaker/fuse panel.  2. Open the switch box. 3. Pull the switch out (without disconnecting any wires). 4. Post a clear photo of the wiring within the box.

Comment: Probably because the motor was an afterthought, and was plugged into a receptacle intended and wired for the light.  The previous occupant learned to live with t,

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like they ran power to the motor and light via the light switch instead of directly to the motor which would have a much smaller, separate set of low voltage wires running to the garage door button.  If you flip the light switch the motor and light now have power which then makes the garage door opening button able to do its job.

The only way you can confirm this is by pulling out the light switch off the wall and looking to see how many sets of wires are in the box. I really can't imagine they've somehow split the power to the light and motor for the garage door at the destination though.  If so, then they aren't utilizing that functionality by having one light switch control it all.  This sounds like they wanted to do something cool, didn't think it through very well, did the work and then realized it wasn't going to do what they intended and left it.  Either that or a bad wiring job.

If you're sure this is how it's controlled and there are no other factors involved, and there is one set of wires running to the single gang light switch, then no, you would not be able to split the power to the light and motor without isolating the power to the light alone and then running power to the motor on a new line that would bypass the light switch.  You'd could check the motors docs though, there may be a way to split power at the motor already which would at least make the job a bit easier.  Bathroom fans with built in lights are doing this to make splitting the fan and the light to separate switches much easier now a days.  You just have to run separate *edit (control power wires) to the unit.

In my opinion, I'd remove the switch from the equation completely, and just make that a junction box with a cover and power the door the way it was intended.

Comment: If there is 1 set the switch is just a switch leg and there is hot and neutral at the light. The lift could be tied in at that box.

Comment: @Ed Beal - yes, thank you for clarifying.  I was trying to imply that, but didn't say it.  They'd still have to split out the light and motor at the motor and run a separate wire to the switch box, then just wire nut it in to the existing power, essentially bypassing the switch.

Comment: So basically just go into the switch and tie off (with wire nuts) all the matching wires to one another? Right? And then I don't have to worry about the kids locking me out by turning the garage light off!? lol

Comment: The 2 wires on the switch would need to be connected together with a wirenut to keep the lift powered all the time (with breaker off) so you can post that it worked.

Comment: @Melodie Usrey - correct, turn off power to that circuit at your electrical box, pull the switch off and wire nut similar colors if two sets of wires exist.  If one set of wires exist then the switch is the end of the line run and you'd need to wire nut the hot to the neutral (black to white in most cases) and then properly label the white wire as now being hot as per code via a black sharpie or black electrical tape on both ends of the wire.  Put a solid cover on the box and turn power back on and test.  If some other wiring scenario exists in that box you'll need to post pics....

Comment: I straight wired it last night and now no more being locked out. Now I'll just (later) go in and piggy back off of that lead wire to install a light. Thanks for all the help!!

Answer (score 0):

Are there two outlets on the ceiling? Try plugging the lift into the other outlet in the receptacle. It's possible that they wired one side to be switched hot, in anticipation of homeowners plugging in a(nother) light, but plugged the lift into the wrong outlet.